# How to map a key to Nerdtree functions such as NERDTree-s / NERDTreeMapOpenVSplit

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm trying to rebind (map a key to) commands like "i" in nerd tree which opens a horizontal split.

Is there a way to do this, or am I just stuck with nerdtree's default binding? I can't find anything about this in the documentation and I've done a good bit of googling and I'm at a loss.

Note: I believe the [bindings are set in this file](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/c2dd750860288b8cf81f6bd5ff49dc5ee76a34d5/plugin/NERD_tree.vim), I just cant figure out how to override them or call the functions they reference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/197977/258674).

```
let NERDTreeMapOpenVSplit='5'
```

This binds the vertical split open command to the 5 key.

**Side Note:** It's a shame the vim stack exchange site never got off the ground. Vim questions and answers are ending up scattered across multiple community sites.